# angular and wsgi-flask on apache

Tags: angular, centos7, mod-wsgi

I can't run both wsgi and angular on apache at the same time.
Although if you remove  or wsgi or angular from the example.com.conf file, then they work, but if they are together, then they don’t. help solve the problem

centos 7

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
    WSGIDaemonProcess app processes=3 threads=20
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/las.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/las.key

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:4200>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
        ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/las.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/las.key
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It looks likes for Server issue  than programming.  You might find abetter support on Server Fault site?

Comment: @Vega Yes, I searched, but I did not find at least an approximate problem

Comment: I meant you could post your question on the other SE site, Server Fault. So you could have an answer there

Comment: @Vega I asked a question there, but no one has answered yet.
Can you tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: I have no idea, but some similar posts could help, I hope. like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45034305/5468463